# .htaccess rewriteRule (./index.php?page=projects&id=$1)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, short

I'm trying to rewrite the URL using htaccess, but I have some problems that I hope you could help me with.

This is the contents of my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=projects&id=$1
```

The following rule works great, it converts this url:

```
peterboruplund.dk/?page=projects&id=projectname
```

to this

```
peterboruplund.dk/projectname
```

But the problem is that I also want to be able to only view a page. Like if I write this url:

```
peterboruplund.dk/?page=info
```

It should go to the page called "info", like this:

```
peterboruplund.dk/info
```

My problem is how can I achieve both things at the same time?

best, Peter

Comment: `peterboruplund.dk/info` - is this physical path?

Comment: It's a dynamic path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have another rule for `/info`:

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=projects&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Great!... this works perfectly, thanks :)... But is it possible to make the rule for "info" dynamic, so when you write any page name it will go to it, if it exists?

Comment: But how to figure out if a page e.g. `/abcd` exists from rewrite rule since everything is going to `/?page=abcd`

Comment: Also if it works out for you can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Okay, but is their a way so you can write anything as a page and not just "info"? It should not check if the page exists

Comment: ok check updated answer, it will also rewrite any `/abcd` URI to `/?page=abcd`