# Rewriting url on htacess file not working

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Using .htacess rewrite rule, I want to convert this link:

```
http://localhost/CodeArk/?page=mypage
```

into

```
http://localhost/CodeArk/mypage
```

This is my current code in .htaccess file but it is not working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^mypage/?$  http://localhost/CodeArk/?page=mypage    [NC,L]
```

And also this is not dynamic, Is there a way to make it work and make it dynamic?

Comment: You can get some hint from below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238393/htaccess-rewriterule-index-phppage-projectsid-1

Comment: Its now working, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?page=(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L] //use this
```

or you can also use

```
RewriteRule ^/CodeArk/?page=(.*)$ /CodeArk/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```